# "from... to..." versus "to... from..."

Tags: word-order

> I am travelling to Prague from London for a couple of days.
>       - Should I exchange my money here in the UK first?

Having to re-read this question on the travel SE site, I was reminded of financial reports on Bloomberg and similar, where a release of new data is often constructed as, for example, *"Full-year profits increased to $4 million from $3.5 million."*

This "to... from..." word-order pattern seems mostly to appear in US-sourced copy.

When using such information in my own reports I would invariably reverse the order - to me, it seems far more logical/normal/readable/scannable to write the starting point first, then move to the end point.

Am I being over-critical? Is there any linguistic rationale for "to... from..." that I am missing?

Comment: In your financial example I'd prefer to see 'up from' or 'down from' depending on the direction. I agree with you on the order, 'from' then 'to' scans better.

Comment: The use of *to...from* vs. *from...to* is entirely contextual and individual. There is no *American* preference. We go to London from (wherever), and *go from $40 to $120*, or profits were increased from 15% to 30%.

Comment: For amounts of money, it can be either depending on the focus. It has nothing to do with the countries.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it is far easier to follow from... to... unless there is a good reason.
Stock quotes seem to have an adequate excuse: the reader's attention is expected to be firmly attached to the current value, with the previous value given as an afterthought.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about attention.

> 1. The ball was passed to ball man from man ball.
> 2. The ball was passed from ball man to man ball.

Both are talking about the same thing.

> 1. About where it went
> 2. Where it came from or who got it there.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use To & From would be to use "To" in the beginning and followed by "From". My reasoning is, it is always fair to start with what you want. For example: I want to change my name to "1XXXX1" from "1XXXX".

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Wouldn't you say that it's preferable to *end* with what you want?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is your opinion, based apparently on your view on what makes most sense. Language use is not determined by any one person's opinion, and often not particularly by logic. Your opinion (or mine) of what would make most sense is not of much value.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at current newspapers and magazines, it does not look like there is an accepted convention here.

However, logically, it seems useful to distinguish between describing (1) quantitative change (where one can formulate a cognitive model, such as an image of an increasing line or a falling object, while reading), and (2) qualitative change (e.g., I changed my name from John to Frank.)  In the case of quantitative change, I believe a cognitive analysis would suggest providing the initial value first in order to facilitate reader formulating a model while reading. However, cognitive analysis would bear on usage only insofar as "ease of reading" rules the day. Either seems grammatical.

In the case of qualitative change, there is no opportunity for model building, no inherent order or direction, so no compelling difference in readability. Thus order seems primarily a matter of style.  There might be cultural and individual  preferences however.

Answer (score 0):

> I am travelling to Prague from London for a couple of days, should I exchange my money here in the UK first?

The context implies air travel and thus in the first example, “London” would be replaced by the name of one of London’s airports, then

There are three possibilities here.

**1.    You are speaking to a person in the UK:**

I am travelling from <s>London</s> Heathrow to Prague for a couple of days,

This relies on the more familiar being placed before the less familiar and more precise being placed before the more general.

**2.    You are speaking to a person who is either Czech or is in the Czech Republic:**

I am travelling to Prague from London for a couple of days,

This relies on the more familiar being placed before the less familiar

**3.    You are speaking to a person in a third country:**

I am travelling from London to Prague for a couple of days,

This relies on the more familiar being placed before the less familiar and the logical sequence of the journey.

Answer (score 0):

Using "to" first, followed by "from", is by far the most commonly used order in newspapers and other publications where the writers typically follow style guides.  However, that does not mean it cannot be changed.  Language evolves.  Different consistent uses cause language to change.  While the aforementioned order is currently most common, many find the order illogical and prefer to reverse it.  As that occurs more and more, we may find the reverse order in more publications.  I, for one, prefer the logical order of "from" then "to".  To those who feel the same, continue to use this order as that will make it become more widely used and acceptable.  Language is changed by use, one person at a time!

Comment: True, language evolves, but that hardly answers this particular question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/429577)